# How to set and manage "current location" in text field?

Tags: ios, xcode, textfield, currentlocation

In my iOS 7.0 app I need to display in a text field the current location... How can I let the user choose the device location instead of a classic address? 
can I use a small icon within the textfield or the user must type "current location" and my app should match this special text?
Should I dynamically change the font style (like map app does) when it's inserted or any property of xcode can support me?